# locally-compact Hausdorff space, equivalent, compact, continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally-compact Hausdorff space and $f\in C(X)$. 
Show that die following statements are equivalent:

a) For every $\epsilon>0$ is the set $\{x\in X:|f(x)|\geq\epsilon\}$ compact

b) The function $\widetilde{f}:X^+\to\mathbb{C}$ defined through $\widetilde{f}_{|X}=f$ and $\widetilde{f}(\infty)=0$ is contiuous.

Hello,

I want to proof the equivalence of these statements and might need some help.

a) "$\Rightarrow$" b)

$f\in C(X)=\{f:X\to\mathbb{C}\quad\text{continuous}\}$. Hence I have to show, that $\widetilde{f}$ is continuous for $x=\infty$, because $\widetilde{f}_{|X}$ is already continuous. Therefore for every neighborhood $V$ of $\widetilde{f}(\infty)$ exists a neighborhood $U$ of $\infty$ with $\widetilde{f}(U)\subseteq V$.

But now I do not really know, how I can use the set $\{x\in X:|f(x)|\geq\epsilon\}$, because we observe $\widetilde{f}$.

Or is my try false? 
Has someone a tip?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are typical neighbourhoods of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$? And what are the open neighbourhoods of $\infty$ in $X^+$?

Comment: Given $\epsilon$, you need to find a neighbourhood $U$ of $\infty$ such that for every $x\in U$, $|\overline{f}(x)-\overline{f}(\infty)|<\epsilon$. What are the neighbourhoods of $\infty$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: The neighbourhoods of 0 in $\mathbb{C}$ should be the balls $B_\epsilon(0)$ The open neighbourhoods of $\infty$ in $X^+$ should be every set $U$ with $\infty\in U$.

Comment: How are the open neighbourhoods of the point at infinity in the one-point compactification described/defined?

Comment: $\tau^+:=\{U\subseteq X: U\quad\text{open}\}\cup\{U\cup\{\infty\}: U\subseteq X\quad\text{open}, U^c\quad\text{quasi-compact}\}$ I do not think quasi-compact is a common translation. It means, that every open cover of $X$ contains a finite subcover.

Comment: I write it without the hyphen, quasicompact. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, quasicompact = compact for subsets of $X$. So the open neighbourhoods of $\infty$ are the complements of compact subsets of $X$. Relate that to the condition in a).

Comment: So are the complements of compact subsets of $X$ the sets for which exists an $\epsilon>0$ with $\{x\in X:|f(x)|<\epsilon\}$?

Comment: Can I do it like this: $U^c$ is compact, because $X$ is Hausdorff. Therefor $U=\{x\in X:|f(x)|<\epsilon'\}$ for an $\epsilon'>0$. Observe now $|\widetilde{f}(x)-\widetilde{f}(x)|=|\widetilde{f}(x)-0|=|\widetilde{f}(x)$|. When $x=\infty$, then $\widetilde{f}(x)=0$ and there is nothing to show. So $x\neq\infty$. Then $|\widetilde{f}(x)|=|f(x)|<\epsilon'$. Choose now $0<\epsilon\leq\epsilon'$ randomly, and we get $|f(x)|<\epsilon\leq\epsilon'$. By the way, is there a way I can write a following question not in this comment section? I often have the feeling that there is not enough space.

Comment: Could someone gives his opinion about my "proof"? Thanks.

Comment: I am a little bit embarassed to ask again, but I would really appreciate further commentary of my thoughts.