# Topology, locally-compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

I already asked this question here: [locally-compact Hausdorff space, equivalent, compact, continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788177/locally-compact-hausdorff-space-equivalent-compact-continuous?noredirect=1#comment3649949_1788177)

So if this repost is not apprechiated, please just delete this thread, but I would really like to get further help, since the question is not fully answered yet.

Let $X$ be a locally-compact Hausdorff space and $f\in C(X)$. Show that the following statements are equivalent:

a) For every $\epsilon>0$ is the set $\{x\in X:|f(x)|\geq\epsilon\}$ compact

b) The function $\overline{f}:X^+\to\mathbb{C}$ defined through $\overline{f}_{|X}=f$ and $\overline{f}(\infty)=0$ is continuous

"$\Rightarrow$"

The topology of the one-point compactification is defined through

$\tau^+:=\{U\subseteq X: U\quad\text{open}\}\cup\{U\cup\{\infty\}:U\subseteq X\quad\text{open}, U^c\quad\text{quasicompact}\}$

Since $X$ is Hausdorff quasicompact=compact for subsets of $X$. So the open neighbourhoods of $\infty$ are the complements of compact subsetes of $X$.

Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $\infty$. 
Hence $U\subseteq X$ open and $U^c$ compact.
By assumption is for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{x\in X:|f(x)|\geq\epsilon\}$ compact. Therefor for every $x\in U^c$ and every $\epsilon>0$ is $|f(x)|\geq\epsilon$. Then for every $x\in U$ exists an $\epsilon'>0$ with $|f(x)|<\epsilon'$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. I need to find a neighbourhood of $\infty$, such that $|\overline{f}(x)-\overline{f}(\infty)|<\epsilon$.

If $x=\infty$, then $|\overline{f}(\infty)-\overline{f}(\infty)|=0$ and there is nothing to show.
If $x\neq\infty$, then $|\overline{f}(x)-\overline{f}(\infty)|=|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|<\epsilon'$.

So I can now choose $\epsilon=\epsilon'$, and the proof is done.

This is what I got out of the linked thread, with the help of Daniel Fischer and  Luiz Cordeiro.

Have I converted their help right?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a mistake at the very beginning: if $U$ is an open nbhd of $\infty$, $U$ is not a subset of $X$, though it is certainly true that $U\cap X$ is open in $X$ and that $X\setminus U$ is compact. The main problem, though, is that your argument is very badly organized and leaves out some important things. In particular, it’s not enough to show that $\overline f$ is continuous at $\infty$: you have to show that it’s continuous on all of $X^+$. Even if you just appeal to the continuity of $f$ (and you really should do a bit more than that, since there are a couple of details to be checked), your proof should at least mention this point.

> Let $x_0\in X^+$; to show that $\overline f$ is continuous at $x_0$, for each $\epsilon>0$ I need to find an open nbhd $U_\epsilon$ of $x$ in $X^+$ such that $\left|\overline f(x)-\overline f(x_0)\right|<\epsilon$ for each $x\in U_\epsilon$.

Now you can split this into two cases, one for $x_0\in X$ and one for $x_0=\infty$. In each case you should explain how to get the desired $U_\epsilon$.

> If $x_0\in X$, the continuity of $f$ ensures the existence of such a $U_\epsilon$. If $x_0=\infty$, let $$K_\epsilon=\{x\in X:|f(x)|\ge\epsilon\}\;;$$ by hypothesis $K_\epsilon$ is compact, so $X^+\setminus K_\epsilon$ is an open nbhd of $x_0=\infty$. Let $U_\epsilon=X^+\setminus K_\epsilon$, and suppose that $x\in U_\epsilon$. Then either $x=x_0=\infty$, in which case $$\left|\overline f(x)-\overline f(x_0)\right|=0<\epsilon\;,$$ or $x\in U_\epsilon\cap X=X\setminus K_\epsilon$, in which case $$\left|\overline f(x)-\overline f(x_0)\right|=\left|\overline f(x)\right|=|f(x)|<\epsilon\;.$$ Thus, $\left|\overline f(x)-\overline f(x_0)\right|<\epsilon$ for each $x\in U_\epsilon$, as desired.

**Added:** For the opposite implication, suppose that $\overline f$ is continuous, fix $\epsilon>0$, and let $K=\{x\in X:f(x)\ge\epsilon\}$; we want to show that $K$ is compact.

Let $B=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|<\epsilon\}$, and let $U=\overline f^{-1}[B]$; since $\overline f$ is continuous, $U$ is open in $X^+$. Moreover, $\infty\in U$, since $\overline f(\infty)=0\in B$, so $U$ is an open nbhd of $\infty$ in $X^+$. By definition, then, $X\setminus U$ is compact in $X$, and

$$\begin{align*}
X\setminus U&=X^+\setminus U\\
&=\{x\in X^+:\overline f(x)\notin B\}\\
&=\{x\in X:f(x)\notin B\}\\
&=\{x\in X:|f(x)|\ge\epsilon\}\\
&=K\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $K$ is compact.

Comment: Do you have a hint to the other implication as well? Is my try false again?

Comment: @MrTopology: I’ve added that direction to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very long a member to this site and I am not sure about every rule yet. I would like to discuss the other implication b) $\Rightarrow$ a) now, and would not like to do that in the "comment section", because the space is not enough. 
Is this not apprechiated in general? I will adapt that in future question then.

b) $\Rightarrow$ a)

Let $\overline{f}:X^+\to\mathbb{C}$ with $\overline{f}_{|X}=f$ and $\overline{f}(\infty)=0$ be continuous.

I have to show, that for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $C_{\epsilon}:=\{x\in X:|f(x)|\geq\epsilon\}$ is compact.
Therefore that for every open cover of $C_{\epsilon}$ exists a finite subcover.

Let $V_\epsilon$ be an open cover of $f(C_{\epsilon})$. Hence $V_\epsilon\supseteq f(C_{\epsilon})$.
Since $f$ is continuous $f^{-1}(V_{\epsilon})\supseteq C_{\epsilon}$ is an open set.

Because $X$ is locally-compact, every point $x\in X$ has a compact neighbourhood $K_x\ni x$.
Hence there exist finite subcovers $U_x$ of $K_x$ for every $x\in f^{-1}(V_{\epsilon})$.
Therefore there exist indices $x_k$ with $k=1,...,n$ and

$\bigcup_{k=1}^n U_{x_k}\supseteq\bigcup_{x\in f^{-1}(V_{\epsilon})} K_x\supseteq f^{-1}(V_{\epsilon})\supseteq C_{\epsilon}$ is a finite supcover.

Thus $C_{\epsilon}$ is compact for every $\epsilon>0$

Comment: Could someone give a feedback to this try?

Comment: You’ve taken $V_\epsilon$ to be a single open set containing $f[C_\epsilon]$; an open *cover* of $f[C_\epsilon]$ can consist of any number of sets, and you’d need to show that only finitely many of those sets are needed in order to cover $f[C_\epsilon]$. I’ll add a proof of this implication to my answer.